# Escaping Regex single-quote creates extra backslashes on repl.it

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

I am trying to write a prototype method that first needs to escape backslashes `\` when the input contains a plain single quote `'`. (I am aware that extending the prototype is bad practice in almost any other circumstance - this is merely a practice problem I'm trying to solve.)

I've checked out the Regex wiki and tried implementing the solutions to several regex-related questions, but I still seem to be missing something. In all of my attempts, I've been unable to 'escape the escape' as shown below:

```
    String.prototype.escapeQuote = function () {
        const regex = /\'/g;
        const str = `${this}`;
        const subst = `\\'`;
        const result = str.replace(regex, subst);
        return result;
    };

    var str = "this method doesn't work...";
    str.escapeQuote();
```

When I run this code, I expect the output to be:

```
this method doesn\'t work...
```

But the output I get when I run it on [repl.it](https://repl.it/Du9k/2) is:

```
'this method doesn\\\'t work...'
```

binding `subst` to `\'` or just `'` doesn't work either (perhaps it goes without saying) - either way the result is:

```
'this method doesn\'t work...'
```

I am pretty fuzzy on Regex, but trying to improve, so I'd appreciate any help you could provide - and, for that matter, any relevant answers I might have missed.

Comment: I'm not clear what you actually want to achieve. Are you trying to prefix each single apostrophe with three slash characters?

Comment: no I'm trying to return a string without the \

Comment: You've mangled the escapes in the stackoverflow comment syntax. Try describing it using the names of the characters.

Comment: "Without the slash characters"? But your example input doesn't have any slash characters to start with.

Comment: Re edit: Shouldn't the line `var str = "this method doesn't work...";` be `var str = "this method doesn\\\'t work...";` then?

Comment: @Quentin no, this method is intended to assume the input will be formatted as a plain string: `'this method doesn't work...'`

Comment: If the input has no slashes in it, what slashes do you want to remove?

Comment: @Quentin the slashes that are added automatically - see https://repl.it/Du9k/2

Comment: That's a rendering artifact of how the REPL you are using represents a string when it displays a string as the result of evaluating your code (notice it also surrounds it with `'` characters to delimit the string). There are no slashes in the string itself. https://jsfiddle.net/tcef1kju/1/ (I think your question is based on a false premise and you'd be better off deleting it).

Comment: @Quentin you are correct - that is a side-effect I was not considering. In the future I'll be sure to include the REPL I'm using (if I'm using one at all). Thanks for your help - would you care to provide this as an answer to the question so I can mark it as the Accepted answer?

Comment: — I've tried to edit the question so the answer actually answers it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a rendering artifact of how the REPL you are using represents a string when it displays a string as the result of evaluating your code.

Note that it also wraps it in `'` to indicate it is a string.

There are no slashes in the string itself, which you can see in this example:

```js
String.prototype.escapeQuote = function() {
  const regex = /(')/g;
  const subst = `\\'`;
  const result = this.replace(regex, subst);
  return result;
};

const str = `doesn't this sound awesome`;
alert(str + "\n\n" + str.escapeQuote());
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use the unescaped string inside a regular expression.

Like this:

```js
String.prototype.escapeQuote = function(){
    return this.replace(/'/g, '\\\'');
}

console.log("Try it, it's easier!".escapeQuote());
```

If you don't like that nasty `'\\\''`, you can use `"\\'"` instead.

Hope this works for you.

---

If you want to escape both single and double quotes, you can use this:

```js
String.prototype.escapeQuotes = function(){
    return this.replace(/["']/g, '\\$&');
}

console.log("Try it, it's easier!".escapeQuotes());
```

Comment: @ZacCollier Sorry the huge delay. I've been extremelly busy. I've fixed the answer.